# How do I make a flat color photo/vector photo from an original photo?

Tags: photoshop

[image][image]

How to easy make my own pictures look like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about creating a non-photograph. This question is probably better suited to [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: @scottb it is an interpretation of what the sensor produces, just  somewhat fewer colors than the JPEG or GIF format... Should we exclude these?

Comment: @xenoid That's an unnecessary slippery slope argument. Surely you agree that there are plenty of examples of graphic design that start with, or incorporate, photographic elements, but are such that on the whole, probably aren't considered _photographic art_. IMO, the examples provided are such cases.

Comment: bendixen: "How do I make a flat color photo/vector photo from an original photo?"  **Those are not photographs**. If you mean to ask *How to photograph graphic art work to best capture the true colors of the art work* than you should re-write your question to address that, **use as much detail as possible when explaining what your goal is**. If you want to ask how to create  graphic art, prints or paintings  that looks like those then this is not the place to ask that.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, The OP did not claim that those posters were photographs. OP asked, how to _manipulate_ a photograph so that it comes out looking like those posters.

Comment: @scottbb, I don't see the slope. OP wants to point a camera at a scene, capture an image, manipulate the image to achieve a certain effect, and then print the image. How is that not photography? Once, many years ago, I took a class in black&white photographic printing. Day 1, the instructor said, "They say pictures never lie. That's B.S., _Every_ photograph is a lie. You're here to learn how to _create_ photographs, from your imagination, using a negative as a starting point."

Comment: @SolomonSlow _How is that not photography?_ When the photographic element is merely an input, but processed to the point it's no longer photographic art, but rather graphic design. To what degree post-processing stops being photography and moves into the realm of graphic design, I don't know. But I do believe the desired goal as exampled by OP are far beyond that point. Xenoid's answer refers to the Shepard Fairey's Obama "Hope" poster. From the standpoint of Fairey's art, it is not photography. It is a stylized stencil portrait of Obama, starting with a photo that Fairey didn't take.

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea is to posterize the image.

Here is a rough first approach. Edit the curves "freehand"

[image]

But as we do not want too much banding on the colors, let's turn it into a grayscale image first and then edit the curves.

[image]

We could now convert the image to palette color mode (3 colors) and edit them.

[image]

But the real additional step is to vectorize the image using a... you guessed, a vector program; Illustrator, Corel Draw, Affinity Design, Inkscape.

[image]

Now you can change the colors of the individual shapes, but also have the "illustration" look because now it is an illustration, not a photo.

[image]

<sub>Original Image: https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/16/17/43/sunset-4854346_1280.jpg</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This kind of color reduction became popular with the "Obama hope" poster, and looking for plugins under than name yields [results](https://sites.google.com/site/elsamuko/gimp/fairey). Another method is to "posterize" the image to reduce the number of colors (and hope for the best) or sample a few dominant colors into a palette and then convert the image to use the palette.

OTOH, you can't take any random picture and expect good results. This will only work with specific images, with good contrast and few colors, and likely significant "manual help".